# Remove islands and completely surrounded polygons after polygonization with QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geoprocessing, spatial-query

I have a line map of buildings in a city. I was able to correctly polygonize the buildings in QGIS with the Polygonize processing algorithm. All the holes/islands became features as expected. Now I need to select and remove all features that are completely surrounded by other (one or more) features. Examples shown in red on the image:
[image: Inner yards to remove]

These are not part of buildings, but inner yards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative is to use "vector > geoprocessing tools > dissolve" (**--Dissolve all--** in the list of dissolve fields), then select the polygons that are "within" the dissolved polygons using the "spatial query" plugin.

Comment: Thanks for this. My next issue here is how to dissolve a large dataset based on touching geometries.

Comment: @csandor You can't dissolve those geometries as well based on a common or shared attribute?

Comment: @csandor see my edit. As for the size, I've successfully used dissolve with hundred thousands of polygons

Answer (score 2):

You can use for example this python script to highlight or delete the features that are completely within another feature.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()  #or the layer you want to use
features_a = layer.getFeatures()
features_b = [feat for feat in layer.getFeatures()]
within_list = list()
for feat_a in features_a:
    for feat_b in features_b:
        if feat_b.id() != feat_a.id():
            if feat_b.geometry().within(feat_a.geometry()):
                within_list.append(feat_b.id())
```

To highlight the features you can use:

```
layer.setSelectedFeatures(within_list)
```

And to delete the highlighted features use:

```
caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
    res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(within_list)
```

As a test result I get for example:
[image]

But before you execute this script please save your qgis file because if you want to process a large file this script probably crashes your qgis.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. As the original picture of mine shows I have a lot of cases when more polygons surround a quasi island, so they are not completely within another polygon.

Answer (score 1):

You can also duplicate layer and then make spatial query with "touches" between them. Works with prepared data.