# Selection on Overlapping Polygons

Tags: polygon, arcgis-10.3, overlay

I have converted a CAD file to GIS format using GIS (from .dgn to .shp)... In one layer I have polygons in which a smaller one is on top of the larger polygon. I can see both polygons however when I select the smaller polygon, the software automatically selects both the smaller polygon and the large one.
IS there anything I could do so that when I select the smaller one, the larger one doesnot get selected?

I don't want to select both and then unselect one of them.

Comment: What version you're using ? In 2.10.1 I can select them separately. Do you need select only one "smaller" polygon or all of them.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It is ArcMAP 10.3.... It is just because there are annotations labels and I want to make it so that when you use the indentify tool and click on the smaller polygon you will have its attributes rather than the large one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any settings that would allow you to select only the top polygons because when you click on the small polygon, you also click on the underlying polygon.

Workarounds:

1. Copy top polygons (if there is a way to differentiate them either by attribute or by size) into a new layer and then make your "large polygons" layers [non-selectable](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00s50000000p000000).
2. Work in the [editing session](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/About_edit_sessions/01m60000002v000000/). When in the editing session, you will automatically get a pop-up that will let you choose what feature to select. You can also click the pop-up icon directly which will switch selection to the next feature in the selection set.
   [image]
3. If you will work with those polygons for months and options 1&2 don't sound good, consider developing a Python script tool which would replace the selection tool (ie, when multiple features will be selected, only the one of smaller size will be left in the selection). This tool can be exposed as a button in the GUI.

Comment: Option 3 sounds like a good solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I could use some of the tips u mentioned to work my way through. It is just because there are annotation labels associated with my small polygons and I want to make it so that when I use the identify tool and click on the smaller polygon I will have its attributes rather than the large one.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this topic:
[Remove islands and completely surrounded polygons after polygonization with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164631/remove-islands-and-completely-surrounded-polygons-after-polygonization-with-qgis/164700#164700)

There is answer how to select surrounded polygons.After that you can make a new layer from selection. (For QGIS)