# Identifying "chains" of adjacent polygons with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a table of polygons (land parcels in a city) and I am trying to identify "chains" of 5 or more adjacent polygons. For example, if each letter is a polygon and each . is empty space, AB.CD.EFG.HIJKL.MNOP.QRSTU.VWXYZ then I want HIJKL, QRSTU and VWXYZ. In real life they aren't in a line like that of course.

The messy solution I used for a first attempt is this query:

`SELECT p1.parcel_c as "Parcel 1", p2.parcel_c as "Parcel 2", p3.parcel_c as "Parcel 3", p4.parcel_c as "Parcel 4", p5.parcel_c as "Parcel 5", ST_Union(array[p1.geom, p2.geom, p3.geom, p4.geom, p5.geom]) as merged_geom FROM abandonded_vacant_lots_table p1 INNER JOIN abandonded_vacant_lots_table as p2 ON ST_TOUCHES(p1.geom, p2.geom) INNER JOIN abandonded_vacant_lots_table as p3 ON ST_TOUCHES(p2.geom, p3.geom) INNER JOIN abandonded_vacant_lots_table as p4 ON ST_TOUCHES(p3.geom, p4.geom) INNER JOIN abandonded_vacant_lots_table as p5 ON ST_TOUCHES(p4.geom, p5.geom) WHERE p1.parcel_c not in(p2.parcel_c, p3.parcel_c, p4.parcel_c, p5.parcel_c) and p2.parcel_c not in(p1.parcel_c, p3.parcel_c, p4.parcel_c, p5.parcel_c) and p3.parcel_c not in(p1.parcel_c, p2.parcel_c, p4.parcel_c, p5.parcel_c) and p4.parcel_c not in(p1.parcel_c, p2.parcel_c, p3.parcel_c, p5.parcel_c) and p5.parcel_c not in(p1.parcel_c, p2.parcel_c, p3.parcel_c, p4.parcel_c)`

As you can see this is clumsy and inelegant and I suspect inefficient. It also returns a lot of almost duplicates when there is a chain of more than 5 parcels, eg if the parcels are ABCDEF it returns ABCDE and BCDEF when a better solution would return the longest chain, ABCDEF. How can I make this query more efficient, more elegant and in general more versatile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have a solution for postgis 2.0+:

First subquery to select the dump of unioned polygons to get only simple polygons and no multies and also get rid of internal edges of touching polygons:

```
with merged_patches as
(select (st_dump(st_union(geom))).geom as geom from abandonded_vacant_lots_table),
```

2nd subquery dumps the simple geoms from the table:

```
all_patches as 
    (select (st_dump(geom)).geom from abandonded_vacant_lots_table)
```

The query will return the count of adjacent polygons in patches and the merged patch geometry:

```
select count(*),merged_patches.geom 
from merged_patches,all_patches
where
```

Where the bbox overlap to speed things up:

```
    all_patches.geom && merged_patches.geom AND
```

The real condition is here: we're checking if the current patch is within a merged patch:

```
    ST_Within(all_patches.geom,merged_patches.geom)
```

Let's group these by the merged_patches:

```
group by merged_patches.geom
```

if you want to return merged_patches with more than 5 sub-patches:

```
having count(*)>=5;
```

Alltogether:

```
with
merged_patches as
    (select (st_dump(st_union(geom))).geom as geom from abandonded_vacant_lots_table),
all_patches as 
(select (st_dump(geom)).geom from abandonded_vacant_lots_table)
select count(*),merged_patches.geom 
from merged_patches,all_patches
where
    all_patches.geom && merged_patches.geom AND
    ST_Within(all_patches.geom,merged_patches.geom)
group by merged_patches.geom
having count(*)>=5;
```

I had a somewhat similar problem ([Remove islands and completely surrounded polygons after polygonization with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164631/remove-islands-and-completely-surrounded-polygons-after-polygonization-with-qgis)) that inspired this answer.

Answer (score 7):

If your "chains" don't necessarily need to be a straight line (i.e, if they can fork), then you can tackle this with the new clustering functions in PostGIS 2.2.  For example:

```
SELECT geom FROM 
  (SELECT unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(geom)) AS geom 
   FROM abandonded_vacant_lots_table) clusters 
WHERE ST_NumGeometries(clusters.geom) >= 5
```

In this query, [ST_ClusterIntersecting](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html) returns an array of `GeometryCollection` entities, each reflecting a potentially forked "chain."  The PostgreSQL function `unnest` turns the array entries into a recordset, forming the `clusters` subquery.  Then, we're selecting only the chains having 5 or more geometries.

The easiest way to link these results back to your original table ("what parcel IDs are in the clusters") is to use a spatial join between the clusters and an interior point of your original geometries.

You may find [ST_ClusterWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterWithin.html) to be more useful, especially if you have parcel polygons that almost touch but don't quite.

Comment: Wow those are awesomely useful functions! I don't have access to PostGIS 2.2 yet. As soon as 2.2 is available on Ubuntu I'll give it a shot.